# CSV->xml, how to eliminate columns

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml.  It is actually a tab delimited file converted to xml.  `<R i="0">` contains the column heading and C=1 to C=8 are columns.  I need to eliminate for example  "Size 1" and "Height 1" and create an xml output.  I only want to eliminate Size 1 and Height 1 from each row and keep the rest.  Can you please help?

---

```
<Message>
<Header/>
<Data>
    <Data>
        <R i="0">
            <C i="0">Sample File</C>
            <C i="1">Sample Name</C>
            <C i="2">Dye</C>
            <C i="3">Size 1</C>
            <C i="4">Size 2</C>
            <C i="5">Height 1</C>
            <C i="6">Height 2</C>
            <C i="7">Peak Area 1</C>
            <C i="8">Peak Area 2</C>
        </R>
        <R i="1">
            <C i="0">100CTRL-NEW3-LOT_2014-01-21_D06.fsa</C>
            <C i="1">100CTRL-NEW3-LOT</C>
            <C i="2">B</C>
            <C i="3">143.84</C>
            <C i="4">148.3</C>
            <C i="5">3331</C>
            <C i="6">2024</C>
            <C i="7">30513</C>
            <C i="8">18020</C>
        </R>
        <R i="2">
            <C i="0">100CTRL-NEW3-LOT_2014-01-21_D06.fsa</C>
            <C i="1">100CTRL-NEW3-LOT</C>
            <C i="2">B</C>
            <C i="3">204.1</C>
            <C i="4"/>
            <C i="5">4461</C>
            <C i="6"/>
            <C i="7">40664</C>
            <C i="8"/>
        </R>
    </Data>
</Data>
</Message>
```

Comment: R index 0 contains column heading and and C elements are the column name  with index to column number.  Thanks.

Comment: Thats not what I asked. Where is the code that shows what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes'/>

<xsl:key name="header" match="C[parent::R/@i='0']" use="@i" />

<!-- copy everything as is -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- except -->
<xsl:template match="C[key('header', @i)='Size 1' or key('header', @i)='Height 1']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

P.S. I am not sure what exactly you mean by "*eliminate for example "Size 1" and "Height 1"*"; it could mean `and` and it could mean `or`; Like Lingamurthy CS I guessed `or`, but it should be easy to change.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am sorry I tried few ways and couldn't figure it out to write code.  
Please help again.  If all un needed columns are defined in a variable, then I need to iterate over these items in a variable and based on then eliminate un wanted
columns from each rows.  Something like this varaiable
<xsl:param name="notNeeded">'size 1', 'Height 1', 'and so on'</xsl:param>

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @user3269443 This answers your question as asked; if you have a different question, either edit your question here or post a new one.

Comment: @user3269443: This answer solves your problem, as far as I can see. Please accept the answer (mark the tick on the left). To a ask a different question open a new post.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the Columns with "Size 1" and "Height 1" by specifying templates which don't do anything for those Columns, and copy rest of it

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="C[. = 'Size 1' or . = 'Height 1']"/>
```

Comment: I have the un-wanted columns defined in xsl:param.  For example noy needed columns are defined as

Comment: <xsl:param name="notNeeded">'size 1', 'Height 1', 'and so on'</xsl:param>

Comment: I have the un-wanted columns defined in xsl:param. For example not needed columns are defined as – 
<xsl:param name="notNeeded">'size 1', 'Height 1', 'and so on'</xsl:param>

Comment: your solution only eliminates columns from R with index 0, I want all columns with index C i =3 and C i = 5 in row one and row 2 to go away as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey, could you post the expected output xml?